# AD thumbnail photo byte format \FF\ and \89\

Tags: directory, active-directory

what will affect the byte format of ad thumbnailphoto attribute?
Im facing an issue where whatever photo i upload with my apps it will start with \FF\ but it is not accepted by exchange. However if upload with exclaimer it will be in \89\ format which able to show in exchange and teams. Ive tried different photo and format still come up with same result.

[image: \FF\ attribute thumbnailphoto]

[image: \89\ attribute thumbnailphoto]